# 3 Micro-USB input Design Question

Tags: transistors, mosfet, diodes, usb

I am wondering how to efficiently manage at least 3 Micro-USB inputs to a single Voltage Bus. I'd prefer if only one port can provide power at once, and to be safe from any backfeeding issues if more that one is plugged in. The purpose is for a multi-function programming board that directs voltage to a device and depending on the port chosen, it will have a different path for D+ & D-.